# pycharm: says package not installed but server runs fine from terminal without any error

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have a  `Django` project. I have installed `django-extensions` from terminal and added `django-extensions` to installed apps.

```
In pycharm i have selected the proper venv path for python interpreter
```

Now in `pycharm` when I run the server it says `django-extension not found`. But I can run the server from terminal without any errors.

In `pycharm > settings > python interpreter` : `django-extensions` is not shown.

I checked `pip` list in terminal and it shows `django-extension` package. Also I can see `django-extension` folder in site-packages. I am not able to understand what's the problem.

```
In Pycharm most of the pacakges are shown but only few are not shown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there was no mistake with pycharm.

I have copied a complete virtualenv with my django project.

Later i found that in the /bin/activate

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/path/to/original/virtualenv"
```

is still pointing to the folder from which i copied the project along with the vistualenv.

It should be

```
 VIRTUAL_ENV="/path/to/present/virtualenv"
```

The packages are getting installed in the original folder. So now everything is working fine

Answer (score 0):

if you are using virtualenv, you need to install it proper way switching off virtualenv by using `deactivate`
and then installing package to your project therefore pycharm will read it in the project interprter folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your project interpreter in pycharm.
It will be at File > settings > project interpreter
In above path you need to select your virtual environment (if not showing then add by clicking on '+' option)and apply then click on OK.
Now it won't show that error message.

Answer (score 0):

- 1.Check if you are using a good virtual environment
- If you have good env click on add icon on right side and add package manual